# javascript constructor property becomes undefined after event is called

Tags: javascript, events, constructor, 2d-games

```
var Context = {
    canvas: null,
    context: null,
    create: function(canvas_tag_id, size){
        this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_tag_id);
        this.canvas.width = size[0];
        this.canvas.height = size[1];
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        return this.context;
    },
    fps:1/30
};

$(function(){

// Initialize
Context.create('canvas', [798, 652]);

var s_size = [Context.canvas.width, Context.canvas.height]; // screen size

function Player(){
    this.rect = [0, s_size[1]-40, 20, 40];
    this.color = 'blue';

    this.create = function(){
        // function for creating player object

        Context.context.beginPath();
        Context.context.fillStyle = this.color;
        Context.context.rect(
            this.rect[0], this.rect[1], this.rect[2], this.rect[3]);
        Context.context.fill();
    };

    this.control = function(){
        // player movement control function

        if (event.which == 39 || event.keyCode == 39){
            alert(this.rect);
        }
    };

    this.update = function(){
        this.rect[0] += 1;
    }
}

// player instance creation

var archie = new Player();

// game loop functions

function events(){
    // Keydown events

    function keydown(){
        window.addEventListener('keydown', archie.control);
    }

    keydown();
}

function update(){
    archie.update();
}

function render(){
    Context.context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    archie.create();
}

function game(){
    events();
    update();
    render();
}

setInterval(game, Context.fps);
});
```

As you can see the problem isn't the organization of the code but the event handler, because the player class's update method is working just fine even though it's created after the event handler.
what exactly is the problem here and how do i solve it?

Comment: What is the constructor? when does it appear as expected and when is it `undefined`?

Comment: the player constructor and it doesn't appear as expected and it's undefined when the event is called in this case when i try to move the player to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the event handler, `this` is always the element the event handler was bound to, not the constructor for the function passed in.

To write your code a lot shorter, you're doing

```
var Player = function() {

    this.rect = "something";

    this.control = function(){
        if (event.which == 39 || event.keyCode == 39){
            alert(this.rect); // NOPE ... this is the element
        }
    };
}

var archie = new Player(); // create instance

window.addEventListener('keydown', archie.control); // some function in the instance
```

If you just have to have the object as the `this` value, use bind

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', archie.control.bind(archie));
```

Also note that your event handler callback is missing the `event` argument, and relying on the global `event`, which is not supported in all browsers (Firefox), so you should be doing

```
this.control = function(event) {...
```

Comment: Thanks i think i understand now. Basically event functions also use the "this" keyword so the constructor and it interfere with one another. Which means the solution is to have the event outside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I often use is to store `this` value in another variable ex. `self` and use that copy in every place so it could be:

```
var Player = function() {

    var self = this;

    self.rect = "something";

    self.control = function(event){
        if (event.which == 39 || event.keyCode == 39){
            alert(self.rect);
        }
    };
}
```

This give you guarantee of use what you want, because `this` is based on context of method execution.